Designing DC-DC buck converter based on the L6981 (L6981C50DR)
I will start by a small description of my system (I will omit any irrelevant information).
The DC DC buck converter that I am designing based on the L6981C50DR serves as the bridge between a smart battery and an esp32 based motherboard, converting the typical 12.8V from the battery to a solid 5V. Experimental values showed that output current ranges from 100mA to 200mA with some peaks close to 300 mA hence the choice of the mentioned converter. After selecting the IC, I have been trying to pick up the required external components but here where things begin to be shady for me.
I already did the calculations for the input and output capcitor and they seem pretty straightforward. But when it comes to the inductor selection, then it does not make any sense anymore, I already selected the inductor with the part number MSS1038T-333MLC from mouser, I will attach a link to it. I selected this inductor based on the suggestions found in the data sheet, I had to make this decision quickly and when I checked the design tool provided by STMicroelectronics the values for the inductance were much higher than the values found by calculations which in confusing. I made the selection and now I wanted to document this, it is part of my master thesis so having a scientific approach, calculations experiments and so on, is needed. Did I make a mistake during the calculations when considering some values or is the design tool just wrong and I have to select a new inductor ?
I will attach the chosen design of the converter with the selected values of the external components and also the calculations and the data sheet for the converter and the smart battery. Please if you have any questions or maybe I missed an important info intentionally.
External components:

Cin: GRT31CR61H106KE01L Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - SMD/SMT 10 uF 50 VDC 10% 1206 X5R AEC-Q200 RoHS Compliant
CinA: GCM31CR71H105KA55L Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - SMD/SMT 1 uF 50 VDC 10% 1206 X7R AEC-Q200 RoHS Compliant
CvCC: same as CinA
CBoot: GRT188R71H104KE13D Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - SMD/SMT 0.1 uF 50 VDC 10% 0603 X7R AEC-Q200 RoHS Compliant
L: MSS1038T-333MLC Power Inductors - SMD 33uH Shld 20% 2.3A 93mOhms AECQ2
Cout: GRJ32EC71E226KE11L Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - SMD/SMT 22 uF 25 VDC 10% 1210 X7S or GRM32ER61A476ME20L Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - SMD/SMT 47 uF 10 VDC 20% 1210 X5R RoHS Compliant (An advice about this selection too would be highly appreciated).

Looking forward to your assistance and any remarks or observations even outside the scope is highly appreciated.



Converter data sheet



Welcome! Please inline a schematic.

Thnx! I attached a hyperlink before to the schematic but now I uploaded a picture instead. I also added the data sheet for the battery that I am using.

Vin=12V, Vout=5V so duty cycle D=0.42.
F=400kHz, so T=2.5µs.
Ton = T.D =1.04µs
During Ton, L has (Vin-Vout) across it, so the inductor current ripple \$ \Delta I = \frac{Vin-Vout}{L} T_{on} \$ = 220mA. This looks alright.
Now inductor choice: it's the right type (shielded power inductor), the chip has a peak current limit of 2.3A and the inductor saturates with 30% inductance loss at 2.62A so no problem with saturation.
Capacitor choice: no issue. You could optimize the BOM by replacing 22-47µF with several 10µF caps in parallel, so you only have 1 part number to order. This also results in lower inductance, but it takes a bit more space. It's fine to use 25V X7R caps on input and output, you can use 50V if you feel extra paranoid.
An important issue is MLCCs lose capacitance when voltage is applied. So you can go to the manufacturer website (using Murata as example) for C-V curves and check how much capacitance you actually have under bias. Then see if that gives you the ripple you want.
All that remains is to not screw up the layout, so always think about the hot loop. This is extremely important.
If you use ESP32 on a module with AMS1117 and you don't like your ESP32 crashing due to the terrible transient response of this LDO causing voltage drops when coming out of sleep, you can replace with LDL1117 from ST. The usual tantalum cap on the output should be replaced with 10µF MLCC too.
Now your doubts about inductor value... You selected a 1.5A buck chip but you only need 500mA peak, unless you have other loads. So most of the app notes for this chip will be geared towards this 1.5A nominal output current, using inductor ripple current probably around 0.8A. You're using it at a lower output current, so it makes sense to reduce inductor ripple current in proportion. Thus you get a larger inductor value. No problem.
To reduce ripple current further, you'd need higher inductance. But if you want higher inductance with the same saturation current, then you need more core material, so it's bigger. So you could use a lower current chip, with a lower current limit, allowing use an inductor with higher inductance and lower saturation current, while keeping it small. It can also be more efficient... sometimes. But is it worth the effort? Probably not. If you wanted the lowest possible ripple voltage on the output, then it would make sense to use a higher inductance value to keep the DC-DC in PWM mode in the usual ESP32 current range, like 30-50mA, and only switch to cycle skipping when it sleeps. But you don't really need it. It'll work fine.
If your battery doesn' have a BMS though, you need over discharge protection.

Could you please explain why 220mA is considered alright ? because in the data sheet that value should be less than 20-40 % of Iout_max = 0.5A which makes it fall between 01A and 0.2A or this difference is not a problem ? I checked capacitors liek you suggested and values still within the required range even in bias. I am using the esp32-c3-devkitm-1. I recalculated for different set of Vin based on Vin max and Vin min but I kept Iout_max at 0.5A for my calcualtions instead, for min duty cycle the inductance looks fine but for max duty cycle and for our typical values the inductance is higher

'the inductance is higher' means that the selected inductor's inductance is higher than the calculated values.

220mA is "close enough" to 200mA XD If you increase the inductance, the DC-DC will spend less time in power saving mode, so you'll get less ripple.
